# Is it possible to save perl hash into bash array?

Tags: bash, perl

I have done some processing in perl, and got the result in perl's hash data structure. Usually in bash, when I try to retrieve result from other script like

```
output=$(perl -E '...')
```

I got the output in string. Is it possible to save the result in bash array?

Comment: Convert your string into an array.  Look at https://www.golinuxcloud.com/bash-split-string-into-array-linux/

Comment: `output=( $(perl -E '...') )`

Comment: @Nick: Please clarify: Do you mean a bash _indexed_ array or a bash _associative_ Array? I guess you mean the latter, but it's better to state this explicitly.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for your comment. Yes, I mean associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a perl variable `hash` is an associative array, please try:

```
declare -A "output=($(perl -e '
$hash{"foo"} = "xx";    # just an example
$hash{"bar"} = "yy";    # ditto
for (keys %hash) {print "[\"$_\"]=\"$hash{$_}\"\n"}'))"

for i in "${!output[@]}"; do
    echo "$i => ${output[$i]}"  # see the result
done
```

The outermost double quotes around `output=..` is required to tell `declare`
to evaluate the argument.

**[Update]**
Considering tripleee's comment, here is a robust version against special characters:

```
mapfile -d "" -t a < <(perl -e '
$hash{"baz"} = "boo";           # example
$hash{"foo"} = "x\"x";          # example with a double quote
$hash{"bar"} = "y\ny";          # example with a newline
print join("\0", %hash), "\0"') # use a nul byte as a delimiter

declare -A output               # bash associative array
for ((i = 0; i < ${#a[@]}; i+=2 )); do
    output[${a[i]}]=${a[i+1]}   # key and value pair
done

for i in "${!output[@]}"; do
    echo "$i => ${output[$i]}"  # see the result
done
```

Comment: This assumes that the value in `hash{$_}` doesn't contain e.g. literal double quotes, which would require additional quoting shenanigans. This is thus rather brittle.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the comment. I've updated my answer with a robust one.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from perl variables to bash variables works only if they are free of null bytes (`\n`), as perl can store null bytes in strings, but bash cannot.
At least, we can use that limitation to print the hash in perl with null delimiters and safely parse it in bash again:

```
declare -A "array=($(
  perl -e 'print join("\0", %hash), "\0"' |
  xargs -0 printf '[%q]=%q '
))"
```

Please note that neither `%q` nor `-0` are specified by posix. For a more portable solution see [tshiono's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66416745/6770384).

If the hash is very big such that `ARG_MAX` might be exceeded you should ensure that `xargs` does not split a key value pair across two calls to `printf`. To do so, add the option `-n2` (or any other number 2*n* where you are sure that *n* key value pairs never exceed `ARG_MAX`).